# Range filter and order by different field Firestore in Angular5

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Using**
Angular5, Firestore 4.12.0

Is there available to load a list from `firestore` using both queries `where('updatedAt')` and `orderBy('count', 'desc')`?

For example,

```js
this.afs.collection<T>(ref, date => date.where('updatedAt', '>=', arg)
.orderBy('count', 'desc')): ref;
```

I know it's not possible to do like above, but I want to know there is a way to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the documents on the client after a filtered query completes.  Or filter the documents on the client after a ordered query completes.

Comment: but is it okay with doing on the client?

Comment: Only you can know that, based on the size of the query result set.  Try it and find out.  If the results set is too big, you'll find out, because it'll take too long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew it actually, I guess sorting on the client is not a good solution, so I'm asking better solution.
Because data will be getting bigger, and then sorting on the client will took much longer